# Change iPhone internet connection mode programmatically

Tags: iphone, connection, wifi, mode, gprs

I want to know if there is a way of changing the internet connection mode from GPRS to WiFi and vice-versa programmatically. I am developing one application and want to give liberty to users which internet connection mode they want to use for my application. Also is there any other connection mode available apart from WiFi and GPRS?

Answer (score 1):

Not with a public API.

There's also Bluetooth connectivity, which is used for GameKit and also automatically used for device-to-device Bonjour.

Comment: Thanks TC for your valuable comments.